# Connect device to Windows 7 hostednetwork -> No Internet Access needed

Tags: networking, wifi, hosted

I 'm looking for a clean way to communicate between an Android/iOS phone and a Windows 7 laptop. No need for internet connection, just a way for a TCP connection between the phone and the laptop.

I have enabled the hosted network, but there is no connectivity. The laptop has 192.168.173.1 and the phone 192.168.173.3 but ping fails and connections between the two devices fail.

Comment: configure your phone as WiFi hostpot, and connect your laptop to it, maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`
Turn on the requested items and specially check `Enable file sharing for devices that use 40- or 56- bit encryption`